# php JSON autocomplete $_POST to another page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have here a select_course.php with AJAX autocomplete. what I am trying to do is pass the array variable pulled in get_course.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#course_no").autocomplete({
            source:'get_course.php',
            remoteDataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            minLength:1
        })
    });
```

and the form with it

```
<form method="post" action="select_course_add.php" name="selectcourse">
<input size="35" type="text" id="course_no" name="course_no" autofocus /> 
<input type="submit" value=" Add " />
</form>
```

get_course.php code

```
$term=$_GET["term"];

$query=mysql_query("
SELECT    
    course_tbl.course_id
    , course_tbl.course_code
    , course_tbl.course_num
    , course_tbl.description
FROM
    cis_db.course_tbl
where course_num LIKE '".$term."%' OR course_code LIKE '%".$term."%'
ORDER BY course_tbl.course_num ASC, course_tbl.course_code ASC
");
$json=array();
    while($student=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
             $json[]=array(
            'value'=>$student["course_num"],
        'code'=>$student["course_code"], 
            'label'=>$student["course_description"]
                            );
        }
echo json_encode($json);
flush();
```

please help, my problem is, how can i convert and use this 3 variable to $_POST **'value'=>$student["course_num"]**, **'code'=>$student["course_code"],** and **'label'=>$student["course_description"]**

Comment: in other words, how do you pass all three values with the form when the submit button is clicked rather than just the value.

Comment: yes, to be able to pass 3 value from auto complete when it is selected instead of the value="course_no">. any tutorial you can direct me?  TIA

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this two lines:

```
remoteDataType: 'json'
type: 'POST'
```

Your requisition must be GET, and by default the ajax call knows that the response type will be Json, so your response must be an array like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3'));
```

If you really need to send more values on the array you can use the select method of autocomplete, to treat as you want this values.